# Windows7, ISS7, ASP Clasico con Access .mdb ; Error en instruccion recordset .addnew

Tags: asp, iis, ms-access, mdb

Agradecería que me orientarais con este problema.
Estoy retocando una aplicación ASP que hasta ahora funciona en entorno XP para que funcione en entorno W7. 
No hay problemas para conectarme y abrir recordsets en lectura a la BD ACCESS (.md) en lectura, pero en el caso de recordsets de escritura da problemas en la propia instruccion ".addnew".

El código es el siguiente

```
'Codigo en fichero "cBD.asp"
'---------------------------- 
 .....

 Set mConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

 mConn.ConnectionString="PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=MiBD.mdb"
 mConn.Mode=adModeReadWrite
 mConn.Open
...

'Codigo en fechero "pagina.asp"
--------------------------------
...
<SCRIPT language=vbscript RUNAT="SERVER" SRC="inc/cBD.asp"></SCRIPT>
...
<%
  set oBD = new cBD
  oBD.OpenConnection 
  'Abro el rs sin problemas
  oBD.OpenRecordSet "MiNombreDeRS",adOpenStatic,adLockOptimistic, "MiNomTabla"
  'Pero esta me da error
  oBD.rs("MiNombreDeRS").addnew
```

Para llegar hasta donde estoy, he tenido que cambiar la antigua conexion JET por la ACE para que las lecturas se puedan realizar. 
Por si se tratara de problemas de (32-64Bits)configuración, también he probado a ejecutar tanto el "AccesDataBaseEngine.exe /passive" como el"AccesDataBaseEngine_X64.exe /passive" pero sin exito.

Comment: El pool de la aplicación, ¿habilitaste compatibilidad de 32bit?. Podrías detallarnos más del error que te sale, al menos una imagen. Para detallar los errores podrías ejecutar: %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:asp -scriptErrorSentToBrowser:true

Comment: Gracias Davlio, Tras activar los detalles de error, el mensaje indica claramente que el fichero .mdb no tiene permisos de escritura ('entiendo que es para el ussuario con el que IIS7 se conecta').

Comment: agrega al grupo `IIS_IUSRS` y dale control total